# Database Storage for Object Initialized Test Data?

Tags: c#, testing

I am working in a solution that has a large number of tests that follow an Arrange/Act/Assert pattern. All of the test data is arranged as object initializers, similar to the following:

```
var animal = new Animal
{
   Id = 10,
   Name = "Skippy",
   BirthDate = new DateTime(2020, 01, 05),
};

// Assertions (fluent assertions)
animal.Name.Should().....
```

Per the client's request, I need to take these tests and manipulate the data (e.g., change all the Animal names and Birth Dates). Some options I thought up:

1. Use regex to modify the data in place (the data is not always well formed, so pattern matching will be hard)
2. Read the data into memory, modify the data in memory, and serialize the data back out to replace the original C# test file data (not sure how to do this replacement)
3. Similar to option 2, except redirect the serialized data to a file/etc and then modify the test to read that serialized data file.

Due to the complex nature of the data, I am thinking that option 3 is the most straight forward option. However, I am also trying to keep the data relatively easy to modify going forward. The object initializers that are used now offer great flexibility and ease of use, and are familiar to the development team, so I would like to keep those if possible.

Does anyone know of a library/etc that will read C# formatted object initializers back into an object of a given type? So the usage would be something like:

```
var animal = _objectReader.Read<Animal>("path_to_test_data");
```

Comment: Many common testing frameworks have "data-driven tests" or something like that, which can be used to pass strings and other values to your test methods, from attributes and also from files. You could also use a JSON file as input. What have you tried?

Comment: Why does your client care about the exact test data for your unit tests?

Comment: @CodeCaster I simplified the data significantly -- some of the test have initializer sections of 10K+ code lines with perhaps 100 'variables' that need to change

Comment: In that case: JSON, or see @Alejandro's comment, and consider that a unit-to-be-tested depending on 10K of setup lines is maybe doing a bit too much.

Comment: @Codecaster yeah. I am thinking JSON is the right way. These aren’t really unit tests, they’re full system integration tests. We only really need maybe 50 or so fields, but the full state is available “just in case”. I am planning to use C# caller info params as a one time generation to force generate the JSON objects when an existing hook is called. Then just need to change a few lines in each test to read from JSON

Answer (score 0):

The problem with serialize/ change/ de-serialize is you lose formats and/or comments in your code.
If Regex is not a option I would write a code to open the code file and make the changes.

Comment: Good point - but the comments in the data block probably don't matter. Or are only minimally useful. Writing code to open the code file and change it is basically a fancy regex replace utility -- which is still going to be difficult because the formatting of the tests is not consistent

Comment: How do you imagine this? Deploy the code with the test binaries and have the unit test read, modify and compile the code file at runtime, then feeding it to the system under test? With what data should the file be modified?

Comment: I think the code option is a bit more flexible than the regex and a bit more readable / maintainable. I was thinking it would be possible to run it as a separate project before the compilation .But if the Codecaster's JSON approach is possible, it's better